# How to get a user input in entry widget without button in tkinter python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="Name:")
label.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

How do I get a user input in entry widget without button in tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

```
window = tk.Tk()

username = tk.Entry(window)
username.pack()

def it_has_been_written(*args):
    #what you want to execute when user starts typing something
    pass
username.trace_add("write", it_has_been_written)

window.mainloop()
```

To see more about this https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html

Comment: Thankyou bro appreaciated! , I'm new here in this kind of community. Thankyou for your help.